# How to get system date in SQL Server with the format of 'MM dd, yyyy'

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How to get the system date in SQL Server with the format of `MM dd, yyyy`?

I tried everything but I couldn't get the correct format `MM dd, yyyy`

Comment: "SQL" is a standard. Please don't abbreviate "SQL Server" to just SQL. (I changed the question title)

Answer (score 3):

Use this query,
`SELECT FORMAT(Getdate(), 'MM dd, yyyy')`

Comment: Please note, that *FORMAT* works starting with *SQL Server 2012*

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107)

**try this query this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
DECLARE @mydate date = getdate()

SELECT CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, @mydate) as varchar) 
      + ' ' 
      + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, @mydate) as varchar)
      + ', ' 
      + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, @mydate) as varchar)
```